# After upgrading to Sierra, "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements."

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, macos-sierra

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing
>   Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those
>   specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

I am specifically asking what can be done about this Xcode error in the case that the OS has been upgraded to Sierra, because that is the only significant thing in my situation that I believe has changed recently

EDIT: my capabilities settings have not changed, so I'm sure it's not that. I have found that it will work with Automatic Code Signing checked, but I'm still curious why all of a sudden it is necessary for me to check this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 'Capabilities' tab in your project settings and see if the all of them are in order. The `PassTypes` entitlement was added anew to Xcode 8, whereas previously this didn't need to be a specific entitlement - it was sufficient if it was turned on in `developer.apple.com`.

When I first migrated to Xcode 8, I got a warning with a `fix issue` option.

Comment: Thanks, I've upvoted because this was the first thing I checked also. However I know my capabilities are correct, they have not changed. I've added a note to my question above